# Padding в строчных элементах

Tags: html, css

Сразу покажу что у меня получается и что нужно получить!

[image: Что получилось]

[image: Что хочу получить]

Суть вопроса:
Как заставить строчные элементы (a, span) нормально реагировать на padding а не переносить его с собой на следующую строку.. собственно как это показано в варианте [Что хочу получить](http://clip2net.com/s/4UyL6U) ?

Answer (score 2):

Для строчных элементов которым нужно установить **padding**, пропишите в файле CSS **display: inline-block;**

Например:

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

**[Здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/css/display)** более подробно.

**UPD:** http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/QVbS7/

Подойдет такой вариант?

Comment: Вариант с display:inline-block не подойдет
[вот](http://clip2net.com/s/4UCnKl) результат

Comment: См. апдейт ответа.

Comment: Вариант с span один из первых которые я рассматривал.. но тут уже привязка с br и разбиению текста ссылки на span программным путем.
Впрочем спасибо большое!